# How do I remove folder if particular extension does not exists?

Tags: files

I have multiple folders which has mp4, 3pg, mp3 files. I want to remove folders which does not have mp4 file in the folder. How can I do that on terminal or by writing bash script ?

Comment: There are many ways you could approach this.  The simplest would probably use something like `count=$(ls $dir/*.[mp4|3pg|mp3]|wc)` for each directory that you'd want to check (loop through).  Note that I consider what you're trying to do very risky and error prone.  I suggest you at least keep a backup of what you would delete, perhaps by moving it to a sort of trash folder.

Comment: Are all those folders on the same depth level in the same directory or do you have to search recursively ? Can they be nested so e.g. `folder1` does not contain any `mp4` files (only `mp3`) but it contains subfolders that may contain `mp4` files - what happens in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have, or don't want to use comm:

Using find, get a list (A) of folders containing mp4 files, get a list of all folders (B). Then get the list of folders in (B) that are not in (A), and process them.

(Untested)

```
(find -type f -name "*.mp4" -printf "%h\n";find -type f -name "*.mp4" -printf
"%h\n";find ./* -type d -printf "%p\n") | sort | uniq -u | while read i;do 
echo mv $i ${TRASHFOLDER};done
```